# What is txpool equivalent in Parity?

Tags: parity

I'm aware of `txpool` module in Geth where it able to show how many transactions in the pending and queue state.

How to get the same result in Parity node? The [parity_alltransactions](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_alltransactions) looks like returning all the transactions and that's not what I'm looking for. I just want to see stats.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [parity_pendingTransactions](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactions) is what you are looking for. According to the documentation:

> parity_pendingTransactions will show the transactions added to the
>   queue that will be processed soon (and do not fulfil any of the
>   droping conditions).

That been said, if a transaction meets the dropping conditions, it will not turn up here.

References:

- [Transaction Queue](https://wiki.parity.io/Transactions-Queue)